# Trying to sort alphanumeric coordinates

Tags: python, sorting, alphanumeric

I have a list of coordinates and I want to sort them by the numbers that are inbetween text and symbols.

```
coords = ['`154blue', '`155blue', 'a154blue', 'a155blue', 'b154blue', 'b155blue', 'c154blue', 'c155blue', 'd154blue', 'd155blue', 'e155blue', '`156brown', 'a156brown', 'a158brown', 'b150brown']
```

I would want it to be listed like this:

```
coords = ['b150brown','`154blue', 'a154blue', 'b154blue', 'c154blue','d154blue','`155blue', 'a155blue', 'b155blue', 'c155blue', 'd155blue', 'e155blue', '`156brown', 'a156brown', 'a158brown']
```

I have tried different sorting and lambda sorting but I cant get it to do it by the numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to obtain the number, and sort first on that then by the underlying string say if there are two coords with the same number:

```
import re

coords = ['`154blue', '`155blue', 'a154blue', 'a155blue', 'b154blue', 'b155blue', 'c154blue', 'c155blue', 'd154blue', 'd155blue', 'e155blue', '`156brown', 'a156brown', 'a158brown', 'b150brown']
coords.sort(key=lambda c: (re.search(r'\d+', c).group(0), c))
print(coords)
```

**Output:**

```
['b150brown', '`154blue', 'a154blue', 'b154blue', 'c154blue', 'd154blue', '`155blue', 'a155blue', 'b155blue', 'c155blue', 'd155blue', 'e155blue', '`156brown', 'a156brown', 'a158brown']
```

Comment: Alternatively `coords.sort(key=lambda s: int(''.join(c for c in s if c.isdigit())))`

Comment: @Stef Post another answer I'll give you an upvote :), also I think you should secondary sort on `s` in case of ties in the numbers, i.e., `lambda s: (int(''.join(c for c in s if c.isdigit())), s)`

Comment: Done. Ironically, the difference between breaking the ties and not breaking the ties is not visible on the input list provided by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `c in '0123456789'` or `c.isdigit` to filter out characters which are not digits:

```py
>>> s = 'b150brown'
>>> ''.join(c for c in s if c.isdigit())
'150'
>>> int(''.join(c for c in s if c.isdigit()))
150
```

Then use this as the `key` argument to `list.sort`:

```py
coords = ['`154blue', '`155blue', 'a154blue', 'a155blue', 'b154blue', 'b155blue', 'c154blue', 'c155blue', 'd154blue', 'd155blue', 'e155blue', '`156brown', 'a156brown', 'a158brown', 'b150brown']
coords.sort(key=lambda s: int(''.join(c for c in s if c.isdigit())))
print(coords)
# ['b150brown', '`154blue', 'a154blue', 'b154blue', 'c154blue', 'd154blue', '`155blue', 'a155blue', 'b155blue', 'c155blue', 'd155blue', 'e155blue', '`156brown', 'a156brown', 'a158brown']
```

Additionally, you can break ties by sorting the strings lexicographically when they have the same number, as suggested by [Shash Sinha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64493890/trying-to-sort-alphanumeric-coordinates/64493955?noredirect=1#comment114046180_64493955):

```py
coords = ['`154blue', '`155blue', 'a154blue', 'a155blue', 'b154blue', 'b155blue', 'c154blue', 'c155blue', 'd154blue', 'd155blue', 'e155blue', '`156brown', 'a156brown', 'a158brown', 'b150brown']
coords.sort(key=lambda s: (int(''.join(c for c in s if c.isdigit())), s))
print(coords)
# ['b150brown', '`154blue', 'a154blue', 'b154blue', 'c154blue', 'd154blue', '`155blue', 'a155blue', 'b155blue', 'c155blue', 'd155blue', 'e155blue', '`156brown', 'a156brown', 'a158brown']
```